# Android WebView scaling video to fit into linearlayout?

Tags: android, video, webview, scale

I have a webview and it displays a video link over the internet. Bu when the video was loaded it scales the view bigger than my linearlayout. But I want it fit into my linear layout. I've tried some methods like LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN or writng the scale property manually but I couldn't find the right solution.

How can I scale it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You may like to try **`setInitialScale`** ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale(int) ). This will help to "zoom" the page (or the video) shown in the Webview to fit a particular width.  Actually the size of HTML5 video in that page is decided by webkit engine and we cannot directly change its size from App layer.

You may also want to calculate the expected **`width`** yourself, due to the fact that Android devices have hundreds of screen resolutions and the width of your LinearLayout may vary on defferent devices.